# Updating Label on previously loaded view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am working on a simple app tab-bar based application that has two views. The first is the main application and the second is a simple instruction screen. What I am trying to do is update a label on that second screen as things change in the main app. Because the second screen is only simple with one label and some text I am not unloading it once its loaded. After the first viewDidLoad I can update the label just fine, but after that is there a way to catch successive view switches (when the view is not loaded) from the tab-bar menu so I can update the label next time the view is swapped?

many thanks

gary

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put code in the `viewWillAppear:` method - this is called every time the view appears, including when a user switches to it using a tab bar.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I am new to this so finding some of these methods is hard going. Very much appreciated.

Comment: I had a similar problem myself ;)
could you mark my answer as the answer please